# What will happen if I try to access data over dblink and the database is down?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Right now, I'm trying to fetch data from production to support via a dblink. But how do I find out whether the production database is down or not? What will be the result when I run the query: `Select sysdate from dual@dblink;` when the production database is down but the support db is up and running?

Comment: It will fail, but exactly what exception you get will depend on how 'down' it is - listener down; server down, DB down, DB mounted, DB unable to archive redo, ... etc. Presumably you won't care about the detail, so does it matter what it fails with? I guess you intend to test this before running your real query; but the DB could still go down in between, or during (or even because of) your real query. Or you looking at a health-check 'ping' to check it is up periodically?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yeah you're right that I do not care about the detail. My intention is only to check whether the DB is up when I'm about to run my real queries. But now, I guess I should consider checking periodically as well. What exactly will be the output when I run `Select sysdate from dual@dblink;` when the remote DB is down? Is it an exception or error or some other output?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the problem the dblink is facing. Most of the time you will get "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified". And the best way to debug is get sysdate from the source if it returns you a date than the system is perfectly fine else there is good possibility that source DB is down.